# How to block a directory for not moving/deleting while my program uses the directory?

Tags: c#, directory, block, delete-file

I was working on a project in visual studio, in my project i need to create some files and folders for backup, but if someone accidentally delete or moved those files or folders that my project/software is using while running then it will shutdown or also can be crashed because i didn't used exception handling. I only need to block access for not moving those directories only while using them.

Comment: "I didn't use exception handling" - That's a mistake.

Comment: lol.. i know.. just beginner, will use later ;), any idead how could i achieve this?

Comment: No, you need to start with exception handling, then as a developer; come up with your own logic on how to handle what you want.  Some ideas: Copy contents of all file into memory, copy files to a "safe" location.  Encrypt the files, hide the files, change permission on files... I'm sure your mind is brimming with ideas.  Enjoy developing!

Comment: As long as you have a file opened in that directory it should not be moveable.

Comment: i know that all.. but i want something easy like 2-3 lines of code will be great.. and my software not always open those file it just open when i have to check or add data to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to achieve that, In the starting of your program you have to open all those files which you don't want others to move or delete, and keep it open until you did not close your application.